# "Email_Sent" message not updating to the spreadsheet as it should

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having trouble with the **"Email _Sent"** text. It is supposed to appear next to the recipient who received the email from my spreadsheet. However, when I select certain emails to send the message to, the text **"Email _Sent"** starts filling out the first empty rows in my spreadsheet. In this way, the text appears beside some recipients who didn't receive the message.

I'll post the script that I'm using:

```
 function sendGeneralEmail() {
  
  var Email = 4;
  var Name = 3;
  var emailSent = 6;

  var subject = "Sample Analysis Service"
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("SUM.1");
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var data = ws.getRange("A5:G" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[5] == true});

  var Email_Sent = 'Email_Sent';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var notBlank = sheet.getRange("D5:G5");

  var lastRow = notBlank.getLastRow();

  data.forEach(function(row){

     html.en = row[Name];
     var htmlMessage = html.evaluate().getContent();

  if(emailSent !=Email_Sent) {

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
   row[Email],
   subject, "Your Email doesn't support HTML", {
    name: "MASAR Team",
    htmlBody: htmlMessage},
    );

    sheet.getRange(lastRow, 7, data.length, 1).setValue(Email_Sent);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  }

});

}
```

Can someone help me to fix that?

The second issue is that, if I run the script and then stopped and came back and run it again on the same day, the text **"Email_sent"** stops updating to the spreadsheet. It only appears the first I run the script during the day.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtKmO.png)
Hope to have a solution to this

Comment: notBlank.getLastRow() is always 5

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a sample spreadsheet or screenshot for us to replicate the data and debug your code.

Comment: I went back to the message above and added a link to a screenshot of my worksheet because I couldn't find a way to post the picture here. I guess I still need to earn 10 more reputations to be able to post pictures

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code and found some issues:

- using `setValue` on range with multiple cells will copy the value to all cells within the range. In your example, all cells in `getRange(lastRow, 7, data.length, 1)` will have the value "Email_Sent". This causes the unwanted write of "Email_Sent" in your spreadsheet.
- `if(emailSent !=Email_Sent)` will always true because '6' is not always equal to 'Email_Sent'

Based on your example, your goal is to send an email and write "Email_Sent" to the **Email Status** column of the recipient.

Here, I fixed some part of your code and added features.

**Code:**

```
function sendGeneralEmail() {
  var subject = "Sample Analysis Service"
  // var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("SUM.1");
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var data = ws.getRange("A5:G" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){ 
    var selected = data[i][5]; 
    var emailStatus = data[i][6]; 
    if(selected && emailStatus != "Email_Sent"){ 
      var email = data[i][4];
      // html.en = row[Name];
      // var htmlMessage = html.evaluate().getContent();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
        email,
        subject, "Your Email doesn't support HTML", {
        name: "MASAR Team",
        message: "ABCD",
        // htmlBody: htmlMessage},
        }
      );
      sheet.getRange(i+5, 7, 1, 1).setValue("Email_Sent");
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: *I commented the html parsing since I don't have the sample html and replaced the email message with a string.*

**Before running the script:**

[image]

**After running the script:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)